# Error while trying to use Mysql for my Java program

Tags: java

I got this error while trying to compile the below code. I suspect that the code is not support MySQL. I want to use MySQL and try to modify it, but it cannot compile.

```
QuadrantSystemRDB.java:183: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable driverName
location:class edu.indiana.iucbrf.examples.quadrantRDBTemplate.QuadrantSystemRD
B
        dbInfo = new DBInfo(new JDBCDriverInfo(driverName, url, username, passwo
rd),constantsTableName);
                                               ^
Note: QuadrantSystemRDB.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

Code:

```
    private void setupInfo() {

    Driver driver = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "123456";

    String problemFeatureSpecTableName = "ProblemFeatureSpec";
    String solutionFeatureSpectTableName = "SolutionFeatureSpec";
    String classTableName = "Class";
    String extraDataTableName = "ExtraData";
    String casebaseTablename = "CaseBase";
    String problemTableName = "Problem";
    String solutionTableName = "Solution";
    String inactiveContextsTableName = "InactiveContext";
    String constantsTableName = "Constants";
    dbInfo = new DBInfo(new JDBCDriverInfo(driverName, url, username, password),constantsTableName);
    problemSpecInfo = new FeatureSpecRDBInfo(problemFeatureSpecTableName, classTableName, extraDataTableName);
    solutionSpecInfo = new FeatureSpecRDBInfo(solutionFeatureSpectTableName, classTableName, extraDataTableName);
    rdbCasebaseInfo = new RDBCaseBaseInfo(casebaseTablename, solutionTableName, problemTableName, inactiveContextsTableName);
}
```

Edit:

Here is my echoed classpath-->

C:\Documents and Settings\user>echo %classpath%
.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\iucbrf\;C:\mysql-connector-ja
va-5.1.14-bin.jar;C:\iucbrf.jar

Edit 2:

I changed `driverName`  to `driver`.
Now the error is...

```
 QuadrantSystemRDB.java:167: unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be
 caught or declared to be thrown
            Driver driver = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
                            ^
 Note: QuadrantSystemRDB.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
 1 error
```

edit 3:

```
try
  {
    Driver driver = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "123456";

catch (Exception e)
  {
   // message.
  }
```

Comment: I think the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197986/what-causes-javac-to-issue-the-uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations-warning

Comment: This is an entirely new question.  But as a pointer, you must catch any exceptions that are thrown by the class initializer (in this case, the exception is SQLException.)  This is a pretty simple problem in Java, so I suggest that you read up on the basics of Java and exception handling before continuing.  (Or mark this as homework.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize but never use `driver`.

You use `driverName` but never initialize it.

Is the solution as easy as changing `driverName` to `driver`? :)

**EDIT**:

> ```
> QuadrantSystemRDB.java:167: unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be
> caught or declared to be thrown
>     Driver driver = new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
> ```

I think the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver()` can throw an exception; you either need to wrap it in a `try/catch` block or declare that your method throws that same exception. Your choice which one leads to a cleaner design, but a simple `try/catch` can allow the compilation to succeed very quickly. :)

Comment: Yep. I did what you suggested. Now no error for that. But new error occurs. I pasted it on my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you declare the variable "driverName"?

Comment: am trying to find it. it is not inside the same file though

Comment: I found at the top of the file, it is declared as this: DBInfo dbInfo;

Comment: Is it declared as a variable somewhere in the enclosing class?  Another alternative:  are you implementing any interfaces in this class?

Comment: That's a declaration for the variable dbinfo.  This is saying that the variable "driverName" is not declared.

Comment: I changed driverName to driver. But still have another error. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice is on this line:

```
dbInfo = new DBInfo(new JDBCDriverInfo(driverName, url, username, password), constantsTableName);
```

Where is driverName declared?