# I'm using JSP with NetBeans and I'm getting the following error

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

Note:

```
C:\Users\Greg\Documents\NetBeansProjects\abalon3\build\generated\src\org\apache\jsp\user2_jsp.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Code:

```
<%
  String like=" ";
  Vector<String> vcd = new Vector<String>();
  Vector<String> vbo = new Vector<String>();
  vcd=CheckUser.search_latest_cd();
  int jc=vcd.size();
  vbo=CheckUser.search_latest_books();
  int jb=vbo.size();
  int i=0;

%>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<table border="1" cellspacing="10"
bgcolor=#99FFFF>
<tr>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Summary</th>
<th>Genre</th>
<th>year</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>ID</th>
</tr>
<%if(vbo.size()>0){for( i=jb;i<jb;i-=7){%>
<tr><td><%out.print(vbo.get(i-6));%></td><td><%out.print(vbo.get(i-5));%></td>
<td><%out.print(vbo.get(i-4));%></td><td><%out.print(vbo.get(i-3));%></td>
<td><%out.print(vbo.get(i-2));%></td><td><%out.print(vbo.get(i-1));%></td>
<td><%out.print(vbo.get(i));}}%></td></tr>
</table>
```

can anyone tell me where's the problem?

Comment: Oh, my eyes.  Scriptlet code should not have a place in the world.

Comment: Please read up-to-date tutorials/books. This is a 90's way of writing JSP/HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing what the message says:

> Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: he can't. It's a generated source file from a JSP being compiled internally by Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Do `vcd=CheckUser.search_latest_cd();` and `vbo=CheckUser.search_latest_books();` return 
`Vector<String>`?

The cause for `unchecked or unsafe operations` is generally that the compiler cannot check the generictype. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197986/what-causes-javac-to-issue-the-uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations-warning) for more detials.

Also, Java `Vector` is deprecated in the later version of JVM. You should consider using `List` and `ArrayList`

Another note, you do not need to create an object which never be used. Here is your code:

```
Vector<String> vcd = new Vector<String>();
vcd=CheckUser.search_latest_cd();
```

You can set the object directly to `vcd`:

```
Vector<String> vcd = CheckUser.search_latest_cd();
```

or

```
Vector<String> vcd = null;
vcd=CheckUser.search_latest_cd();
```

Creating new `Vector` object which is never be used is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

And last but not least, what you're seeing is not an error but a warning from the compiler (though some compilers can be set up to handle warnings as errors, this isn't the default behavior of the Sun Java compiler).