# -Xlint unchecked in java

Tags: java, compilation, javac, unchecked

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What causes javac to issue the “uses unchecked or unsafe operations” warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197986/what-causes-javac-to-issue-the-uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations-warning)

Im getting following warning. What is -xlint:unchecked. 
If i include -xlint:unchecked in build.xml, Im getting lot of warnings.

```
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

How to resolve this. Please help

Comment: Did you check [enter link description here][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197986/what-causes-javac-to-issue-the-uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations-warning?rq=1

Comment: In the `javac` task add option `-Xlint:unchecked`!

Comment: Should i include @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") in all the java files to overcome this?

Comment: @user1549683: Absolutely not. You should avoid the unchecked operations wherever possible, and only suppress warnings when you've got a *really* good reason to.