# unchecked or unsafe operations even after specifying type

Tags: unsafe, unchecked-exception

I get the following warning

Note: com.......\BeerSelect.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

I have specified the type as well.. I would like to know the reason rather than using the @SupressWarning option.

I checked the other threads as well
[What causes javac to issue the "uses unchecked or unsafe operations" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197986/what-causes-javac-to-issue-the-uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations-warning/197993#197993)

The below is the piece of code..

```
    package com.example.web;

    import com.example.model.*;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     IOException, ServletException{
    String c = request.getParameter("color");
    BeerExpert be = new BeerExpert();
    List<String> result = be.getBrands(c);
    ServletContext sc = this.getServletConfig.getServletContext();


    request.setAttribute("styles",result);
    RequestDispatcher view =    getServletConfig.getServletContext().getRequestDispathcer("result.jsp");

    view.forward(request,response); 
}
```

}

Any sort of help is appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes javac to issue the "uses unchecked or unsafe operations" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197986/what-causes-javac-to-issue-the-uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations-warning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
Iterator<String>
```

instead of Iterator
This happens because the Iterator interface is generified. And BTW its not an error but just a warning. hope this helps

Hi, 
I've slightly modified your code and it should get compiled with no warnings:

```
public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     IOException, ServletException{
    String c = request.getParameter("color");
    BeerExpert be = new BeerExpert();
    List<String> result = be.getBrands(c);
    ServletContext sc = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
    request.setAttribute("styles",result);
    RequestDispatcher view = sc.getRequestDispatcher("result.jsp");

    view.forward(request,response);
}
```

}

I think the only way to get such a warning here is from BeerExpert class, if for example it returns List and not List like this:

```
public class BeerExpert {

public List getBrands(String color) {
    return new ArrayList(); // really dumb implementation, you should have something smarter here
}
```

}

I suggest you to check this out and if needed to change to :

```
public class BeerExpert {

public List<String> getBrands(String color) {
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

}

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help.. But, I tried 'Iterator<String>' but still I get the same warning.. 

Corrected it as warning in the question as well..

Comment: Well, i guess you should post the warning here. It should point you on an exact line in the code that causes this warning

Comment: Am getting the same warning message as above in the post..

Note: com.......\BeerSelect.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. 

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details

Comment: Can you post the source of BeerSelect.java file here then?r

Comment: I had the specified the type in the body of the method getBrands(), but dint specify for the return type.. 

Thanks for all your help :)