# Gradle compile error Android Studio -Xlint:unchecked for details

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

**WHEN I INSTALL MY APPLICATION AT API23, IT WORKS FINE.
BUT WHEN I INSTALL MY APPLICATION AT API 16-17, IT DOESN'T EVEN COMPILES
& THROWS BELOW WARNING.**

How do i get rid of this warning, or atleast how should i correct my mistake.

**Error at the time of running my application:**

> Error:Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note:
>   Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. FAILURE: Build failed
>   with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>     com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
>     0xffff]: 65536
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

**My app level Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chsoneresidential.chsone"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false        // true by default
        checkAllWarnings false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        ignoreWarnings true       // false by default
        quiet true                // false by default
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    // Try to turn them all off automatically
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:none'
    options.compilerArgs << '-nowarn' // same as '-Xlint:none'

    // Turn them off manually
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-auxiliaryclass'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-cast'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-classfile'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-deprecation'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-dep-ann'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-divzero'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-empty'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-fallthrough'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-finally'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-options'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-overloads'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-overrides'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-path'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-processing'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-rawtypes'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-serial'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-static'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-try'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-unchecked'
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-varargs'
}
```

**app.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }

    tasks.withType(org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile){
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

References : [Uses unchecked or unsafe operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617901/uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations)

[How do I suppress warnings when compiling an android library with gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148513/how-do-i-suppress-warnings-when-compiling-an-android-library-with-gradle)

Comment: Check the solution of @Aspicas in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643102/android-studio-2-1-instant-run-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313101/dexindexoverflowexception-only-when-running-tests

Comment: @Raghavendra : It gives new error : Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.
Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : It worked, Thanks.
Please post as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: @Pawan Honestly speaking, I am not here for more reputations . Here for Friendship and knowledge transfer . I can't violet `Stackoverflow's `duplicate answer rule . Move ahead .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : Still Thanks Bro :-)