# why do i get and how to fix it

Tags: java, compiler-errors

This is my error

```
Note: Question2. java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint : unchecked for details.
```

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Question2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
 
//Declare a panel for displaying message
private MessagePanel messagePanel;

// Declare two buttons to move the message left and right
private JButton jbtLeft, jbtRight;

// Declare Combo Box,radioButtons,CheckBox, TextField, Interval
private JTextField jtfNewMessage = new JTextField(8);
private JComboBox jcboInterval = new JComboBox();
private JRadioButton jrbRed = new JRadioButton("Red");
private JRadioButton jrbGreen = new JRadioButton("Green");
private JRadioButton jrbBlue = new JRadioButton("Blue");
private JCheckBox jchkCentered = new JCheckBox("Center");
private JCheckBox jchkBold = new JCheckBox("Bold");
private JCheckBox jchkItalic = new JCheckBox("Italic");

// Declare the Font name, Font style, Font size 
private String fontName = "SansSerif";
private int fontStyle = Font.PLAIN;
private int fontSize = 12;
 
/** Default constructor */
public Question2() {
setTitle("Question2");

// Create a MessagePanel instance and set colors
messagePanel = new MessagePanel("Welcome to Java");
messagePanel.setBackground(Color.white);

// Create Panel jpButtons to hold two Buttons "<=" and "right =>"
JPanel jpButtons = new JPanel();
jpButtons.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
jpButtons.add(jbtLeft = new JButton());
jpButtons.add(jbtRight = new JButton());

// Set button text
jbtLeft.setText("<=");
jbtRight.setText("=>");

// Set keyboard mnemonics
jbtLeft.setMnemonic('L');
jbtRight.setMnemonic('R');

// Set icons
//jbtLeft.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image/left.gif"));
//jbtRight.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image/right.gif"));

// Set toolTipText on the "<=" and "=>" buttons
jbtLeft.setToolTipText("Move message to left");
jbtRight.setToolTipText("Move message to right");

// Place panels in the frame
getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
getContentPane().add(messagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
getContentPane().add(jpButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

// Register listeners with the buttons
jbtLeft.addActionListener(this);
jbtRight.addActionListener(this);

/** 1.Add a text field labeled “New Message.\
 *    Upon typing a new message in the text field and pressing the Enter
 *    key, the new message is displayed in the message panel.
 */
jpButtons.add(new JLabel("Enter a new message"));
jpButtons.add(jtfNewMessage);

jtfNewMessage.addActionListener(this);

/** 2.Add a combo box label “Interval\uFFFD that enables the user to select
 * new interval for moving the message. The selection values range from
 * 10 to 100 with interval 5. The user can also type a new
 *  interval in the combo box.
 */
 jpButtons.add(new JLabel("Select an interval"));
 jpButtons.add(jcboInterval);
 for (int interval = 5; interval <= 100; interval += 5)
  jcboInterval.addItem(interval + "");
 
 jcboInterval.addActionListener(this);
 
 /**
 * 3.Add three radio buttons that enable the user to select the foreground
 * color for the message as Red, Green, and Blue.
 */
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
 
 panel.add(jrbRed);
 panel.add(jrbGreen);
 panel.add(jrbBlue);
 ButtonGroup btg = new ButtonGroup();
 btg.add(jrbRed);
 btg.add(jrbGreen);
 btg.add(jrbBlue);
 jrbRed.addActionListener(this);
 jrbGreen.addActionListener(this);
 jrbBlue.addActionListener(this);
 
 /**
 * 4.Add three check boxes that enable the user to center the message
 * and display it in italic or bold.
 */
 panel.add(jchkCentered);
 panel.add(jchkBold);
 panel.add(jchkItalic);
 jchkCentered.addActionListener(this);
 jchkBold.addActionListener(this);
 jchkItalic.addActionListener(this);
 
 /**
 * 5.Add a border titled Message Panel on the message panel.
 */
 messagePanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Message Panel"));
 jpButtons.setBorder(new TitledBorder("South Panel"));
 panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("North Panel"));
 
 this.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
 }
 
 /** Main method */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Question2 frame = new Question2();
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.setSize(520, 200);
 frame.setVisible(true);
 }
 
  /** Handle button events */
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == jbtLeft) {
      messagePanel.moveLeft();
      messagePanel.repaint();
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == jbtRight) {
      messagePanel.moveRight();
      messagePanel.repaint();
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == jtfNewMessage) {
      messagePanel.setMessage(jtfNewMessage.getText());
      messagePanel.repaint();
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == jcboInterval) {
      messagePanel.setInterval(
        Integer.parseInt((String)(jcboInterval.getSelectedItem())));
      messagePanel.repaint();
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == jrbRed) {
      messagePanel.setForeground(Color.red);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == jrbGreen) {
      messagePanel.setForeground(Color.green);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == jrbBlue) {
      messagePanel.setForeground(Color.blue);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == jchkCentered) {
      if (jchkCentered.isSelected())
        messagePanel.setCentered(true);
      else
        messagePanel.setCentered(false);
   
      messagePanel.repaint();
    }
    else if ((e.getSource() == jchkBold) ||
             (e.getSource() == jchkItalic)) {
      
        fontStyle = Font.PLAIN;
    
      // Determine a font style
      if (jchkBold.isSelected())
        fontStyle = fontStyle + Font.BOLD;
      if (jchkItalic.isSelected())
        fontStyle = fontStyle + Font.ITALIC;
    
      // Set font for the message
      messagePanel.setFont(new Font(fontName, fontStyle, fontSize));
    }
    }         
    public class MessagePanel extends JPanel {
    private String message = "Welcome to Java";
    
    private int xCoordinate = 206; //x coordinate where message is displayed
    private int yCoordinate = 29; //y coordinate where message is displayed
    private boolean centered;//indicate whether message is displayed in the
    center
    private int interval = 10; // interval for moving message left/right
    
    public MessagePanel() {
    }
    
    public MessagePanel(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
        repaint();
    }
    
    public int getXCoordinate() {
        return xCoordinate;
    }
    
    public void setXCoordinate(int x) {
        xCoordinate = x;
    }
    
    public int getYCoordinate() {
        return yCoordinate;
    }
    
    public void setYCoordinate(int y) {
        yCoordinate = y;
    }
    
    public boolean isCentered() {
        return centered;
    }
    
    public void setCentered(boolean centered) {
        this.centered = centered;
        repaint();
    }
    
    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }
    
    public void setInterval(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
        repaint();
    }
    
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    
        if (centered) {
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    
            // find the center location to display
            int stringWidth = fm.stringWidth(message);
            int stringAscent = fm.getAscent();
     
            // get the position of the leftmost character in the baseline
            xCoordinate = getWidth() / 2 - stringWidth / 2;
            yCoordinate = getHeight() / 2 - stringAscent / 2;
        }
      
        g.drawString(message, xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
       }
       
       public void moveLeft() {
        xCoordinate -= interval;
        repaint();
       }
      
       public void moveRight() {
        xCoordinate += interval;
        repaint();
       }
       
       //@override
       public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 30);
       }  
       }
       }
```

I checked out half a dozen posts here on the same error, but I couldn't
figure out what was going wrong.
had create many different file but i got same error repeatedly.
have identify my errors there,this is a coding of GUI`enter code here`

Answer (score 2):

Because your opening and closing brackes { and } are chaotic.

```
public class MessagePanel extends JPanel {
```

This is inside a method and thus will not work. Add a } before it. At the end of the file you also need an additional } at least.

I would suggest putting each class in its own file. This is the most clear way, especially for beginners.

And you have two duplicate methods (moveLeft, moveRight) there. And you should check your variables:

`jbtleft` is not the same as `jbtLeft`

Comment: I have add all in its own file, but what is duplicate file? is it i should delete it from the coding

Comment: "Duplicate file"? I have no idea what you are talking about, sorry.

Comment: i have improve my coding but i got error like (Note : Question2.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.) (Note : Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.)?? what this mean?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197986/what-causes-javac-to-issue-the-uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations-warning

Comment: i have try my best to solve this coding but could not,see my coding i have edited to the correct one. but when i run i getting same error many time, (Note : Question2.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.) (Note : Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.) can u please help me to fix it.where what should i do? i tried many time and i don't understand the link you send @Florian Schaetz