# How to fix unsafe operations?

Tags: java

Here is an extremely simplyfied version of my recent project, which demonstrates the problem:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Class{
        List<Character> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Character> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
        List getList(){
                return l1;
        };
        void setList(){
                l2.clear();
                l2.addAll(getList());
        };
}
class Main{
        public static void main(String[]args){
                Class object = new Class();
                object.setList();
        };
}
```

When I compile it, the compiler says:

> Note: Class.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile
>   with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

When I take `l2.addAll(getList());` away, then the compiler doesn't return that message, but obviously this screws over my project.

What are unchecked or unsafe operations and how can I fix them?

Comment: `List getList()` should be `List<Character> getList()`

Comment: Unsafe means the compiler doesn't know if the elements you are added are safe to add. Use generics consistently is the easiest way to fix this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/197986/3385651

Comment: BTW, `class Class` may not be the best name. Java already has a [rather notable class named `Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Comment: Did you "`Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.`"?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
List getList(){
```

**specify the type paramater**, like

```
List<Character> getList(){
```

Before, you were returning a raw type, instead of a generic one.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the compiler's advice:

```
$ javac -Xlint:unchecked Class.java
Class.java:11: warning: [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method addAll in interface List is applied to given types
                l2.addAll(getList());
                         ^
  required: Collection<? extends E>
  found: List
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
Class.java:11: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
                l2.addAll(getList());
                                 ^
  required: Collection<? extends E>
  found:    List
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
2 warnings
```

This makes it very clear that the unchecked conversion is because you're passing a `List` where a `Collection<? extends E>` is required.

So you can fix it by changing the type of `List` to `List<E>` (or `List<? extends E>`); in other words, make the return type of `getList()` non-raw.