# Android studio build error after update to v 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio

Got prompted for an update and let it do its thing and got these errors everything worked fine before the update.

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar,
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources,
>   :app:compileDebugSources]
>   /Users/.../topografie/activity/FlashCardActivity.java
>   Error:(60, 14) error: cannot find symbol method
>   addOnPageChangeListener()
>   /Users/.../topografie/activity/MainActivity.java
>   Error:(87, 14) error: cannot find symbol method
>   addOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener)
>   /Users/.../topografie/activity/MuscleDetailActivity.java
>       Error:(58, 14) error: cannot find symbol method
>   addOnPageChangeListener()
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. 
> Information:BUILD FAILED in 2s 
> Information:4 errors 
> Information:0
>   warnings 
> Information:See complete output in console

Gradle console says:

> symbol:   method addOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener)
>   location: variable pager of type ViewPager 
> Note:
>   /Users/.../MuscleDetailActivity.java uses unchecked or unsafe
>   operations.
>  Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>  1 error

I've come across several similar questions, but none of the answers worked for me. I've cleaned and rebuild the project and I updated all the dependencies in Gradle. EDIT: Gradle syncs fine, but the project build gives error

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.anatomie.bny.topografie"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.AndroidDeveloperLB:AutoFitTextView:4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Please help, I've been at it for hours and can't find a solution

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this problem? Think I have the same problem and I've been scratching my head for hours

Comment: No, unfortunately i didn't find a way to solve this, I ended up creating a new project and copying the classes and resources to that new project and everything works fine now. it's quite the workaround, but i can continue working on it now.

Comment: Eek, that is not the response i was hoping for! Thanks for getting back to me though!

Answer (score 0):

Delete .gradle and .idea folder

And REBUILD

If that doesn't work, again delete .gradle and .idea folder

and RESTART

[image: DELETE THIS]

Comment: Alternatively, invalidate caches/restart. Usually works with these things

Comment: to additionally try Clean Project and try Invalidate cache / restart

Comment: took me a bit to find those folders, but it didn't resolve my issue unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can try my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47070211/5333711). And also restart Android Studio after following these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Change the plugin version in your project-level build.gradle file as follows:

buildscript {

```
repositories {
    ...
    // You need to add the following repository to download the
    // new plugin.
    google()
}

dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
}
```

}

then Rebuild project

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197986/what-causes-javac-to-issue-the-uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations-warning