# Execution failed for task after updating android studio to 3.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

When I updated my Android Studio 3.0, I get an error

```
unable to merge with dex.
```

Then I added `mutiDexEnabled true` and also added `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1` in `build.gradle`.

Then I'm getting the error below:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\KnightFox-IN BUDGET\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\play-services-ads-lite-11.4.2.aar\9a54afd7907fee993ecc421b66ed4228\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:com/google/ads/mediation/MediationServerParameters$Parameter.class]))

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.copperseeds.android.kunjachamman.applicationin.budget"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

}



dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation project(':ORMDroid')
    implementation project(':FacebookSDK')
    implementation project(':standOut')
    implementation files('libs/gcm.jar')
    implementation files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'    
}
```

Comment: have you tried cleaning project?

Answer (score 1):

Try delete build folder of app than **Clean-Rebuild-Run** your Project.
if not work than do **Invalidate Caches/Restart.**

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Try buildToolsVersion `"26.0.0"` and then just restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add **`jar`** files for Play services when you adding **`dependencies`**

remove this from your **`Build.Gradle`**

```
implementation files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
```

than **`Clear-Rebuild-Run`** your Project

Comment: I removed the jar file,but it is not worked for me.I get the same error again

Comment: @jasmin remove this also **`implementation files('libs/gcm.jar')`**

Answer (score 0):

Once try these steps,

**Step 1:** Delete all the **build** and the **.gradle** folder,

**Step 2:** Add the below code in your **gradle.properties**,

```
 android.enableAapt2=false
```

**Step 3:** Then Sync your android project.

Comment: i cant see the gradle.properties

Comment: If not there you can create resource bundle by clicking right click on project,
**Right click on the Project -> New - >Resource Bundle**.

Then create a file named **gradle**. Your **gradle.properties** file will be show just below of **build.gradle** file. Then write this code there.

Answer (score 0):

You should not work with librairies that end with + . You should specify a version.         `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`
should be

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
```

then build.gradle will be :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.copperseeds.android.kunjachamman.applicationin.budget"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }

}



dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation project(':ORMDroid')
    implementation project(':FacebookSDK')
    implementation project(':standOut')
    implementation files('libs/gcm.jar')
    implementation files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to still add in manifest if you are not extending application class

```
  <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
```

If you are extending application class then follow details in this link:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

> Do not use jars, just use the repos directly
>
> do not use compile use implimentation

Also you need to update to Android Studio version 3.0. Also make sure you added the new repo in root gradle.build:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

You may also use with newer gradle wrapper

```
repositories {
        maven {
            google()
        }
    }
```

If you have used data binding in repo then make sure you have added

```
android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

This is the best way to do it.

In your root level gradle.build use below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file change the wrapper version as below

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip
```

Also in your app level build.gradle make sure you are using 26 version as below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```