# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error during gradle build in android studio. And I am unable to figure out what I am missing.

Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3. Searched in the 
    following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android 
    Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android 
    Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.jar
    https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom
    https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.jar

Here is my `build.gradle`file configuration

```
`
all sub-projects/modules.
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
            maven {
                url 'https://jitpack.io'
            }
        }
    }

    buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                name 'Google'
            }
        }
    }

    ext {
        supportlib_version = '26.0.2'
        gps_version = '11.2.0'
    }

    //Ensure that all dependencies use the same version of the Android Support library
    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                    details.useVersion "$supportlib_version"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                    details.useVersion "$gps_version"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                name 'Google'
            }
        }
    }
`
```

Could you help me what am I missing?

Comment: Are you connected to internet? If you are on proxy network put the proxy in android studio.

Comment: Yes, I am connected to the internet. And I am not using any proxy.

Comment: Are you importing a project or creating one from scratch?

Comment: When I am opening this link https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.jar (the one showing in error) there is no such file available. Am I referring to some wrong repository in my build.gradle file?

Comment: Importing a project

Comment: Well the project gradle file is culprit. Update the gradle file with a new created project gradle also include required dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

Add jcenter() to buildscript repositories if you are using gradle plugin 2.x.

---

Here's a copy of build.gradle(Project) from my old project.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // for 2.x
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

---

If your gradle (the one distributed by [Gradle](https://gradle.org/)) version is low,
also need to edit gradle-wrapper.properties.

Minimum version of Gradle is 3.3 for plugin 2.3.3.

> Plugin version 2.3.0+ :
>   Required Gradle version 3.3+

gradle-wrapper.properties sample:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Please see [Update Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html?hl=ja#updating-gradle).  Available versions are listed in this [page](https://gradle.org/releases/).

---

For information:

This exists (jcenter).
https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/2.3.3

This does not exist (Google's Maven repository). It's from 3.0, I think.
https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom

This exists
https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom

---

For Gradle version >= 3.0.0

Please see [Update the Android Plugin for Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html?hl=ja#updating-plugin)
and [Update Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html?hl=ja#updating-gradle).

Comment: I have added jcenter(). Still its giving me following error.  `Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.jar    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.pom    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.3/gradle-2.3.3.jar`

Comment: Seems accessing Google's maven repo. How about commenting out `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' name 'Google' }` in  buildscript repositories?

Comment: I have only this in build script `buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}`

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: As a newbie, `Minimum version of Gradle is 3.3 for plugin 2.3.3.` helped me. I had thought those were the same thing that should match versions.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the right version of the gradle and gradle plugin

If you are using plugin 2.2.3 you should use gradle 2.14.1+.
If you updated your Android Studio, you should use plugin version 3.0.0+ with gradle 4.1+.

Please, take a lok at documentation:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Gradle plugin: `build.gradle` project file
Gradle: `gradle-wrapper.properties` file

Answer (score 0):

i hit the similar issue recently after upgrading Android Studio to 3.0. You might want to do some cleanup (erasing .gradle and .idea folders) and rebuild, as discussed in [Android studio build error after update to v 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47064658/android-studio-build-error-after-update-to-v-3-0).