# unchecked call to setModel(ListModel<E>)

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listmodel

In my application, in which I have two JLists, I'm trying to show the contents of the second one depending on what is selected in the first one. Let's say I have group 1, group 2 and group 3 at List1, and when I select Group 1, I want List2 to display what I have at Group 1, and so on. I have actually coded it, and it works, but it gives this warning:

```
[unchecked] unchecked call to setModel(ListModel<E>) as a member of the raw type JList
            exampleGroup2.setModel(group2Container.get(exampleGroup1.getSelectedIndex()));
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class JList
1 warning
```

I've read similar questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197986/what-causes-javac-to-issue-the-uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations-warning), about generics and so, and they resolved similar problems which gave a similar warning, in which I had to specify the `<String>` type, but it doesn't help here.

The line itself, where the warning pops out, is this one:

```
exampleList2.setModel(list2Container.get(exampleList1.getSelectedIndex()));
```

Where everything is declarated as:

```
DefaultListModel<String> list1Container = new DefaultListModel<>();
ArrayList<DefaultListModel<String>> list2Container = new ArrayList<>();
list2Container.add(new DefaultListModel<>());

JList exampleList1 = new JList<>((ListModel<String>) list1Container);
JList exampleList2= new JList<>((ListModel<String>) list2Container.get(0));
```

Sorry if it's a bit messy, I've tried to make it as short and clear as possible. As I said, I've looked on generics, and so, but I cannot find where should I put the `<String>`, or even what do I have to put, in this case.

Thank you very much, for your help.

Comment: Just like all the similar questions, you need to declare your JList type. So `JList<String> exampleList1 = new JList<>(....);`, and same for exampleList2.

Comment: Shoot, your link already tells you this -- why didn't you just follow what the answer tells you to do?

Comment: As the warning was about the setModel() method, and also it specified that line, I thought the problem was there... Also, didn't thought JList needed to specify a type (as every other type of list, I realize now...). Anyway, thank you very much, it solved the problem.