# Why does adding list.add("SuppressWarnings") output a warning in Eclipse and not in Intellij?

Tags: java, list, ide, warnings, suppress-warnings

This is the Code i found in a book:

```
list = new ArrayList();
list.add( "SuppressWarnings" );
```

So in Eclipse, this code gave me those warnings:

> Note: ABC.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

But as i tried it in Intellij, everything was fine. Whats the problem with this code and what is this code doing, cause that was not described in my book?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Or Alternativly: [What causes javac to issue the “uses unchecked or unsafe operations” warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197986/what-causes-javac-to-issue-the-uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations-warning)

Comment: The first one does not, I already know, why there is a raw type warning. As i recompiled it with -Xlint i goth other warnings:
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type ArrayList
list1.add("SuppressWarnings");
^
where E is a type-variable:
E extends Object declared in class ArrayList
(I left the ones with raw type away)
And this warning I don't understand.

Comment: The warning happens because you are using a raw type and adding to a raw type is an unsafe operation. I'm not sure why this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Now I do understand. Thanks for the help.